# Linux: Tail -f multiple options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, tail

I want to add multiple tail scripts in one.

First one:

```
tail -f /var/script/log/script-log.txt | if grep -q "Text1"; then echo "0:$?:AAC32 ONLINE"
fi
```

I want to add 5 more lines with a diffrent word, is this possible?

else if, if etc. etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an example of the log file content and the output you expect?

Comment: Can you not just use or within your grepped text and so grep -E "example1|example2"

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -f /var/script/log/script-log.txt | if grep -E "Text1|Text2|Text3"; then echo "0:$?:AAC32 ONLINE" fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, i want to echo different things. If text = X then echo X etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's enough to use logical `AND` operator:

```
tail -f /var/script/log/script-log.txt | grep -q "text1\|text2\|text3" && echo "0:$?:AAC32 ONLINE"
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, i want to echo different things. If text = X then echo X etc.

Comment: @user3130478, what is `X` in your case?

Comment: I want to check if there is a word in the log file, if the word exits is has to echo something.

Comment: @user3130478, it works exactly so: if matches found - print "something", otherwise - print nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

PIPENAME="`mktemp -u "/tmp/something-XXXXXX"`"
mkfifo -m 600 "$PIPENAME"
tail -f /tmp/log.txt >"$PIPENAME" &

while read line < "$PIPENAME"
do
    echo $line # Whatever you want goes here
done

rm -f "$PIPENAME"
```

If you want Bash specific, you can use the `-u` option for read, and then you can rm the named pipe before the loop starts, which is more guaranteed to leave things clean when you're done.